# Ao criar arquivo, apaga no final da execução

Tags: java

Estou com o seguinte comportamento estranho.
Estou criando um arquivo texto, usando FileWriter e BufferedWriter. Ao final da execução (void main), o arquivo gerado é eliminado.
Se eu debugar e interromper a execução, o arquivo é mantido.
Percebi que esse comportamento começou, a partir de alguma versão do Java.
Alguém passou por isso?

```
public static void write( String dir, String fileName, boolean append, String content ) {
    FileWriter fw = null;
    BufferedWriter bw = null;
    try {
        fw = new FileWriter(new File(dir,fileName),append);
        bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(content);
        bw.flush();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    } finally {
        try {bw.close();}catch(Exception e) {}
        try {fw.close();}catch(Exception e) {}          
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[RESOLVIDO] - No FileUtil tem o método delete, que estava com File file = New File(....
Esse código deveria estar deixando uma referência de memória, que gerava esse comportamento.
Alterei para:
public static boolean delete(String dir, String fileName) {
return new File(dir,fileName).delete();
}
Arquivo mantido!